# make many styled component properties dependent on prop

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I love that you can do

```
color: ${p=>p.active ? 'red' : 'green'}
```

but this syntax gets kind of out of hand for more that one property at a time

```
${
  p => p.active ? (
    `
      color: ${p.theme.red};
      text-decoration: underline;
    `
  ):(
  ``
  )
}
```

compared to the much nicer syntax for classnames

```
&.active{
 color: ${p => p.theme.red}
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However, setting classes conditionally is much less elegant that just setting a prop on a component. Is there a better way to accomplish this that has the advantages of both? Something like

```
&${p=>p.active}{
  color: ${p.theme.red}
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: you can use two different styled components and conditionally render one or the other

Answer (score 1):

You can define the active CSS as a separate fragment, e.g.

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const activeCss = css`
  color: ${p => p.theme.red};
  text-decoration: underline;
`;

const Link = styled.a`
  color:#000;
  ${ p => p.active && activeCSS }
`;
```